# replacing .info/connected in version 3

Tags: firebase

I have code using:

```
function onConnected(callback) {
    ref.child('.info/connected').on('value', connectedSnap => callback(connectedSnap.val() === true));
}
```

I am not clear how to migrate this code to version 3 ? that is how to have a callback called with true when fb is connected and false when disconnected ?

(the migration docs at https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-web do not mention .info/connected)

thx!

Comment: That code should run without modification. What problem are you having?

Comment: oh in that case there may be another issue ... so is .info/connected still the correct way to achieve this in v3 ?

Comment: ok I see there's a sample in https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#how-ondisconnect-works

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and solved with some like this:

```
var firebase = require("firebase");

firebase.initializeApp({
  serviceAccount: "path-to-your-config-folder/your-config-file.json",
  databaseURL: "https://your-app.firebaseio.com"
});

var db = firebase.database();
var ref = db.ref('/your-data-tree');

ref.set({iAmOnline:true})
ref.onDisconnect().set({iAmOnline:false})
```

My code is for the backend, but maybe can be useful for you.